# Angular Upgrade 9 to 10

Tags: angular

I am trying to upgrade the angular from 9 to 10 , and stuck here with the below error message, i tried to manually upgrade in package.json. But this is not helping :

```
"@angular/core": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/common": "^10.2.5",
```

> ```
> The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
> Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
> √ Package successfully installed.
> Using package manager: 'npm'
> Collecting installed dependencies...
> Found 92 dependencies.
> Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
> ```

```
          Package "@mat-datetimepicker/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.2.4" (extended), would install "10.2.5").
          Package "@mat-datetimepicker/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^8.2.4" (extended), would install "10.2.5").
```

> × Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found. Peer
> dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those
> dependencies might not work correctly together. You can use the
> '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead
> address these warnings later.   See
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-fEmwhD\angular-errors.log" for
> further details.

Any idea what i am doing wrong ?

> Attached error logs:

```
[error] Error: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
    at _validateUpdatePackages (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\angular-cli-packages-rR5gQq\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\commands\update\schematic\index.js:164:15)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\angular-cli-packages-rR5gQq\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\commands\update\schematic\index.js:653:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are upgrading the angular with single major version (i.e you can upgrade from version 6 to version 7, or version 7 to version 8, do not jump like, version 7 to version 9.).

If the above one is a warning than no need to worry, If you have found any error message at the end than please share the same.

Comment: I am doing in the same way Migration failed: is the error message i fell ?

Comment: Please share the log file "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-fEmwhD\angular-errors.log" that you have found in your command line.

Comment: shared in question.

Comment: I think you forget to attach the same, please check again.

Comment: Please check this text Attached error logs:

Comment: did you run ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10 or ng update @angular/core @angular/cli?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233114/discussion-between-jaypal-sodha-and-rohitesh).

Answer (score 1):

While updating the angular core version, also check its dependencies compatibility.

for example,
if you're upgrading whether that specific library is updated for that version and its dependencies which you see in a log while upgrading.

here,

```
Package "@mat-datetimepicker/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^8.2.4" (extended), would install "10.2.5").
```

@mat-datetimepicker/core is not upgraded and it requires @angular/common version ^8.2.4.
but once you upgraded your @angular/common version will be 10.2.5.

So update package, dependency and angular core.

Thanks

Comment: But, the up-gradation of peer dependency can be done manually ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that manually, while upgrading itself it states which version you need as per the current angular version.